# How to display group data based on end date?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a table like below:
[image]

How can i display the data based on task end date with new table. Meaning that, the full <div tag`` will repeat for each ending date and display the records on columns. For example-

```
                                        **Staff 1**
```

Date: 2020-11-14
[image]

Date: 2020-11-27
[image]

```
                                         **Staff 2**
```

Date: 2020-11-14
[image]

Thanking in anticipation.

```
<div>
<table class="table table-bordered">
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Task Name</th>
<th>Remarks</th>
<th>Start Date</th>
<th>End Date</th>
</tr>
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM dl_fullremarks ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
foreach ($result as $row) {?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['staff_id']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['task_name']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['task_remarks']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['task_startdate']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['task_enddate']; ?></td>
</tr>
    <?php
}
?>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: It depends on where do you want to do that sorting, from your query,  backend or frontend?

Comment: @AngeLOL Thanks for your positive response. You attached any approach that I can try and let you know the feedback.

Comment: Its a matter of changing your query. Everything else stays the same. if your end_date column is of data type `datetime` then a query simple as `"SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE end_date = $end_date"` will do. if you want some form ordering then you can at the end of the query add `ORDER BY column_name ASC|DESC`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch your data first with SQL and then organize it with a PHP associative array :

```php
$data = [];
foreach ($result as $row) {
    // Check if the current end date is part of the array. If not, add it
    if (!isset($data[$row['task_enddate']]) {
        $data[$row['task_enddate']] = [];
    }
    // Add the row to the assigned end date
    $data[$row['task_enddate']][] = $row;
}
```

`$data` nows contains the following structure :

```
[
    '2020-11-14' => [
        ['staff_id' => 1, 'task_name' => 'name', // ...],
        ['staff_id' => 2, 'task_name' => 'other name', // ...],
    ],
    '2020-12-16' => [
        ['staff_id' => 3, 'task_name' => 'name', // ...],
    ],
]
```

You can now loop through it to display your template :) !

```php
foreach ($data as $date => $rows) {
    echo '<div>';
    echo "<div>$date</div>";
    echo '<div class="row">';
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        // Display your row data here
    }
    echo '</div></div>';
}
```

Comment: seems like your hints working properly but I am having problem with nested looping. could you please help me add loop through $data for displaying my template?

Comment: I edited my comm with a quick loop example :). You have to make a nested loop.

Answer (score 0):

Group result set by `task_endtime`:

```sql
SELECT * FROM dl_fullremarks
WHERE staff_id = '1'
ORDER BY task_endtime
```

When `task_endtime` changed from last saved then print header. All other rows are printed as in your example.

```php
$prev_endtime = null
foreach ($result in $rows) {
  if (date('Y-m-d', $row['taks_endtime']) != $prev_endtime) {
    echo '<div class="header">date formatted here</div>';
    $prev_endtime = date('Y-m-d', $row['task_endtime']);
  }
  echo '<div class="row">row cells gere</div>';
}
```

Comment: I tried your hints but Its displaying only 1 record from each end date... So how can overcome that problem please?

Comment: Hm.. Please check the result if it contains correct data. We are expecting to see all records groupped by `task_endtime` (eg. in phpMyAdmin). Oh.. it seems I found a bug in my code. I compare date and time, but we need to compare only date part. Add modification in answer.

Comment: I think "group by" clause select all the records and group it by end date and display only first record from that group not displaying all records according to the group

Comment: @Luco, even it so I didn't use aggregate functions so each record is a group so they should be ordered by `task_endtime`. But let's replace `GROUP BY` with `ORDER BY`. Try to debug the `foreach`. it should work because algo is simple. The `header` row is printed only when it different then previous one. All other rows are printed as in your example.